# C#: Do not show result in comand line when result is 0

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm having a task for school in C#. I'm having this issue with the following code (example)

```
static void Main()
{
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Amount of centimeters?: ");
        double centimeters = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        double meters = centimeters / 100;
        Console.WriteLine($"Amount of meters: {meters}");

        int wholeMeters = (int)meters;
        Console.WriteLine($"Amount of whole meters: {wholeMeters}");

    }while (true);
}
```

## Result:

- Amount of centimeters?: *350*
- Amount of meters: 3,5
- Amount of whole meters: 3

---

- Amount of centimeters?: *50*
- Amount of meters: 0,5
- Amount of whole meters: **0**

---

If the result gives 0 for "Amount of whole meters", I don't want to show the line "Amount of whole meters:" in the console.

Like this:

- Amount of centimeters?: *50*
- Amount of meters: 0,5

How can I achieve that, only using the 'System' namespace?

Comment: how about using `if`

Comment: The question might also be, if  `x != 0` or `x > 0` ?

Answer (score 2):

You will pretty sure learn about control structures in the very near future.
Just check the value of your `wholeMeters` field and act on the result

```
if(wholeMeters != 0)
   Console.WriteLine($"Amount of whole meters: {wholeMeters}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually this was my exercise, and I found the result by going true the code again step by step (Took me 1 day !!! :) )

```
static void Main()
{
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Timespan in seconds?: ");
        int timeInSeconds;

        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out timeInSeconds))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is:");

            double amountOfDays = timeInSeconds / 86400;
            if (amountOfDays != 0)
                Console.WriteLine($"- {(int)amountOfDays} days");

            double amountOfHours = timeInSeconds / 3600 - ((int)amountOfDays * 24);
            if (amountOfHours != 0)
                Console.WriteLine($"- {(int)amountOfHours} hours");

            double amountOfMinuts = timeInSeconds / 60 - ((int)amountOfHours * 60) - ((int)amountOfDays * 24 * 60);
            if (amountOfMinuts != 0)
                Console.WriteLine($"- {(int)amountOfMinuts} minuts");

            double amountOfSeconds = timeInSeconds - ((int)amountOfMinuts * 60) - ((int)amountOfHours * 60 * 60) - ((int)amountOfDays * 24 * 60 * 60);
            if (amountOfSeconds != 0)
                Console.WriteLine($"- {(int)amountOfSeconds} seconds");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a positive integer!");
        }

    } while (true);
}
```

}

- Timespan in seconds?: 34567788

  - This is:

    - 400 days
    - 2 hours
    - 9 minuts
    - 48 seconds
- Timespan in seconds?: 34567

  - This is:

    - 9 hours
    - 36 minuts
    - 7 seconds Timespan in seconds?: 2345 This is:
    - 39 minuts
    - 5 seconds
- Timespan in seconds?: 45

  - This is:

    - 45 seconds
- Timespan in seconds?: twenty

  - Please enter a positive integer!

I knew I had to use the if statement, but I had my (double) variables declared at the start of the code instead of right before each calculation.

Thanks for the help anyway!